# Sample Standard Deviation in JQ

Tags: json, jq, standard-deviation

I've an array of numbers and I need to calculate the **Sample Standard Deviation** using `jq`.

Sample Standard Deviation formula ([credits](https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/GVy7U2pn2FP2Tut4MG53ZiCgOCQ=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/calculate-a-sample-standard-deviation-3126345-v4-CS-01-5b76f58f46e0fb0050bb4ab2.png)):
[image: Standard Deviation formula]

I've tried splitting the code into multiple pieces (length, mean), but none of my attempts worked because I don't know how to merge all the data into a single `sqrt` and `map` operation:

```
# Example of data input
_data="[73,73,76,77,81,100]"

_length=$(echo "$_data" | jq --raw-output 'length')
_mean=$(echo "$_data" | jq --raw-output 'add/length')

_standard_deviation=$(echo "$_data" \
                      | jq --raw-output \
                           --arg length "$_length" \
                           --arg mean "$_mean" \
                           '') # <- sqrt and map ?

echo "$_standard_deviation" # Should print 10.237187
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
(add / length) as $mean | (map(. - $mean | . * .) | add) / (length - 1) | sqrt
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/LhK4pixoXxe)</sup>